# showing Premature end of file

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jsp

when i run the jsp page 
it shows 
 **** D:\projects\saxco\build.xml:1: Premature end of file.****
i am not using any Framework.its my content in **content.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/saxco"/>
```

Comment: How do you include the XML file in JSP ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your xml files (web.xml, context.xml ?) are correctly formed.

Most likely you have an unmatched quote in an attribute somewhere, although unclosed elements can also result in errors.